# calling a function from button click in custom php plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom alert plugin so that whenever a comment has been submitted in wordpress it would fire the plugin function to show an alert notifying the user that their comment was posted successfully.

Now i am able to display the alert once a comment has been posted but i would like a way to remove/close the alert by the user. I added a (x) button in the alert and the intention is when the user clicks it - the alert will go away.

This is what i have in my **functions.php** that gets fired when a comment has been submitted:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'comment_custom_alert());
```

This is what i have in my **custom-alert.php**:

```
function close_custom_alert() {
    echo "hello - testing method.";
    // code to hide alert div
}

function comment_custom_alert() {
   ?>
    <div class="custom-alert" id="comment_custom_alert">
        <div class="alert-success">
            <button type="button" onclick="close_custom_alert()" class="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Your comment has been posted successfully.
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

but when i click on the button i see in the console that ***close_custom_alert is not defined***. Not sure what i might be missing or doing wrong.

I also tried:

```
<button type="button" onclick="<?php close_custom_alert() ?>" class="close">&times;</a>
```

But after trying it out i would get *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some js for this:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
```

update your html to this:

```html
    <div class="custom-alert" id="comment_custom_alert">
        <div class="alert-success">
            <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()" class="close">&times;</button>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Your comment has been posted successfully.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does remove it but when i refresh the page the div reappears. What is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: probably need some logic in your php to check if popup has been shown before.